# Schedule Cron wih Bash

Tags: bash, shell, cron

This is the command I want to run:

```
00 03 * * * backup.sh
```

I understand that this will run the script backup.sh at 3am every morning. How can I add this cron command on my linux server using a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As root:

`echo "00 03 * * * root backup.sh" >>/etc/crontab`

or

`echo "00 03 * * * root backup.sh" >/etc/cron.d/mybackupjob`

As your own user:

`crontab -l >tmp; echo "00 03 * * * backup.sh" >>tmp; crontab tmp; rm tmp`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add this cron command on my linux server using a bash script?

If you want to run this *as root*, you could place a file in `/etc/cron.d` named `backup` with the following contents:

```
00 03 * * * root backup.sh
```

This assumes that `backup.sh` is in the standard `PATH`, you probably want to use a fully qualified path here instead of relying on `PATH`:

```
00 03 * * * root /path/to/bin/backup.sh
```

On many distributions, you could also place (probably via a symlink) the `backup.sh` script into something like `/etc/cron.daily` and it would run every night.  This is often simpler and more maintainable than writing your own crontab entries.

If you want to run this *as a user*, you can run...

```
crontab -e
```

...to edit your own crontab file and adding the entry there:

```
00 03 * * * /path/to/bin/backup.sh
```

Note that there we don't need to specify a user name (that's only necessary in `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/crontab`, and other global system locations.

Comment: This looks good, thank you. What is the bash command needed to actually add the line to crontab -e though?

Comment: `crontab -e` brings up an editor.  You type in the line and save the file and exit your editor and this activates your new crontab file. You can also type `crontab /path/to/your/crontab` to install a crontab from an existing file instead of using your editor.  Also, `man crontab` and `man 5 crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

You know about the /etc/cron.d directory, right? If not, type 'man cron'.

Comment: You put a file in that directory written out by you bash script. The format is the same as that of a regular crontab, with the addition of an extra file (the second-to-last) giving the user to run the job under.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e` will attempt to invoke your `EDITOR`, so your first script could set this to a second script which just has to append the line in question to the crontab:

```
#!/bin/sh
EDITOR=/path/to/second/script crontab -e
```

Second script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "00 03 * * * /path/to/bin/backup.sh" >> $1
```